# Can't quite get NSURL working to POST

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, post

I have an iOS app that uses NSURL to send data to a server, where its retrieved in Python. Here's my relevant NSURL code in Xcode:

```
NSString* base=@"http://gpselftracker.appspot.com/scan";

NSURL* URL=[NSURL URLWithString:base];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

NSString *postString = @"?latitude=";
NSString* postString1=[postString  stringByAppendingString:latitude1];
NSString* postString2=[postString1 stringByAppendingString:@"&longitude="];
NSString* postString3=[postString2 stringByAppendingString: longitude1];
NSString* postString4=[postString3 stringByAppendingString:@"&altitude="];
NSString* postString5=[postString4 stringByAppendingString: altitude1];
NSString* postString6=[postString5 stringByAppendingString:@"&speed="];
NSString* postString7=[postString6 stringByAppendingString: speed1];
NSString* postString8=[postString7 stringByAppendingString:@"&heading="];
NSString* postString9=[postString8 stringByAppendingString:heading1];
NSString* params=[base stringByAppendingString:postString9];

NSData *data = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request addValue:@"8bit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Transfer-Encoding"];
[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:data];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                              delegate:self];

[connection start];
```

And here's what happens on the server to retrieve the values:

```
def post(self):
    params=list()
    session=get_current_session()
    latitude=self.request.POST["latitude"]
    longitude=self.request.POST["longitude"]
    altitude=self.request.POST["altitude"]
    speed=self.request.POST["speed"]
    heading=self.request.POST["heading"]
```

I realize that some of the code, esp the concatenation in Obj-C, is sorta nasty, but I had this working a few months ago, lost the source, and am trying to recreate from scratch. When I run this, the error I get in the GAE log console is:

```
'latitude'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 716, in __call__
handler.post(*groups)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~gpselftracker/1.372388516394179216/main.py", line 43, in post
latitude=self.request.POST["latitude"]
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/webob/multidict.py", line 302, in __getitem__
return self._decode_value(self.multi.__getitem__(key))
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/webob/multidict.py", line 77, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key)
```

KeyError: 'latitude'

Comment: off topic - But why are you using 9 strings when you can append all in to 1 string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this maybe.

```
NSMutableString* postString9 = [base mutableCopy];//i dont know if you want to change the base string so I decided not to in this example.
[postString  stringByAppendingString: @"?latitude="]; 
[postString  stringByAppendingString:latitude1]; 
[postString9 stringByAppendingString:@"&longitude="];
[postString9 stringByAppendingString: longitude1]; 
[postString9 stringByAppendingString:@"&altitude="];
[postString9 stringByAppendingString: altitude1];
[postString9 stringByAppendingString:@"&speed="];
[postString9 stringByAppendingString: speed1];
[postString9 stringByAppendingString:@"&heading="];
[postString9 stringByAppendingString:heading1];

    postString9= (NSMutableString*)[urlsString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *data= [postString9 dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding   allowLossyConversion:YES];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:base]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval:20];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; 
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Oh, turns out that your advice was right! I followed your example and it worked, now to refactor my code into something that doesn't look as horrible...

Comment: If you want to make code nicer you can put it on  codereview.stackexchange.com